# Return type of a text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here, `$scope.cd` is returning a `null` value. How can I get the correct value? What is the return type of this text box? Here, the controller is power and the application name is `myapps`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapps', []);
app.controller('power', function($scope) {
  $scope.increase = function() {
    $scope.cn = null;
    $scope.cp = null;
    $scope.employe.name = "kalyan";
    if (1) {
      $scope.employe.points++;
    } else {
      alert("Incomplete Credentials");
    }
    alert($scope.cn);
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> Employe page</h1>
  <div ng-app="myapps" ng-init="employe={name:'Arjun',attendence:1,points:1}" ng-controller="power">
    <h4> Name: <span ng-bind="employe.name"></span></h4>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>
          Attendence: <span ng-bind="employe.attendence"></span></p>
      </li>
      <li> <input type="text " ng-model="cn" value="Candidate name">
        <input type="number " ng-model="cp" value="944-"></li><br>
      <button ng-click="increase()">Enter</button>
    </ul>
    <p> Points: <span ng-bind="employe.points"></span> </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no reference of $scope.cd , is it cn or cp ?